# arcpy.sa.RasterCalculator tells me the input raster is invalid when I use a complicated python expression

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

Some brief background: I am dealing with a raster band whose data consists of a 16-bit unsigned integer. Each of the bits of this integer conveys separate pieces of information about the quality of satellite imagery bands (landsat 8) within the same raster. For example `22280` in binary is `00010001101010`, with bit #3 (`1`) indicating cloud cover for that cell/pixel, and remaining bits indicating water, ice, cirrus clouds, cloud shadows etc., as well as confidence level of these indicators.

I am writing a Python script to process rasters of this type. In particular, I would like a raster that isolates bit #6, i.e. has values of `0` or `1` depending on bit 6 of the integer. This is a code snippet I am running in an ArcGIS pro notebook to test out this approach:

```
expression = "int('{:b}'.format(x)[8])"
RC_output = arcpy.sa.RasterCalculator([qa_band],
                                     ['x'],
                                     expression)
RC_output.save(is_clear_band)
```

This gives an error:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to apply Raster Function: 'RasterCalculator' (The parameter is incorrect. 
The table was not found. [Band_3])
```

It seems obvious that I have an error in the `qa_band` variable that I am using,  *however, I do not think that is the issue*, for two reasons: 1) I used the 'copy path' feature straight from the catalog pane to assign `qa_band`, and 2) when I replace `expression` with `"x+1"` the code executes with no issues. It seems like something about the expression is causing the error.

I'm running ArcGIS Pro 3.0.2.

Comment: I think your expression needs to be:  `expression = "'{:b}'".format(x)[8]`.

Comment: That returns `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`. I believe the whole expression needs to be a string which is then executed as a python command. Since `x` is not defined outside of the RasterCalculator execution, the above doesn't work. Nevertheless, I appreciate the suggestion Hornbydd.

Comment: However, that did cause me to take another look at my `expression` string. As is, it would return strings of `'0'` or `'1'`, not integers (`0` and `1`) as I intended. So I edited the expression to `"int('{:b}'.format(x)[8])"`. It also gives the same error, so I will make that change in the original post.

Comment: For anyone still reading this: [this link](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/raster-functions/calculator-function.htm) indicates the limited set of operations that are available within the python expression. These do not include the string method `format()` of course. They mostly include algebraic and logical operators and functions. I believe I can come up with an algebraic expression that gives me what I want using the `%` operator.

Answer (score 1):

On the off chance that anyone finds themselves in a similar situation, here is the solution I used to extract a desired bit from an integer in a raster. As mentioned in a comment above, [this link](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/raster-functions/calculator-function.htm) explains that only a limited set of operators and functions, mostly focused on algebra and logic, are available to use in Python expressions for Raster Calculator. This is the solution I came up with using those capabilities:

```
b=6
expression = 'Int(Con(x % 2**({}) >= 2**{}, 1, 0))'.format(b+1, b)
RC_output = arcpy.sa.RasterCalculator([qa_band], ['x'], expression)
```

This solution works for my data. Hope this is helpful to someone eventually.
A few quick follow-up notes: 1) use `Int` and not `int` in raster calculator, this ensures the output raster data is actually an integer, 2) if anyone from ESRI is reading this, consider taking another look at how the error output from Raster Calculator communicates what is really going wrong.